# excepción bucle foreach c#

Tags: c#

buenas estoy aprendiendo a programar en c# estoy haciendo un ejercicio que dice lo siguiente.

Una enumeración “Dia” con los días de la semana.

Una interfaz “ILibre” con una propiedad bool llamada diaLibre.

Una clase llamada “ToDoList” que herede de la interfaz “ILibre” y que
contenga una variable de la enumeración “Dia”, también contendrá
una matriz de `string` llamada tareas, y una función con parámetros para darle valor al elemento de la matriz

En el programa principal tendremos una variable array de ToDoList de
un tamaño de 7.

En la ejecución del programa además de instanciar los objetos que necesitemos, le damos el tamaño a la semana y mediante un bucle recorreremos cada día preguntando si es fiesta, y si no es fiesta preguntaremos por las tareas.

En el bucle `for` recorremos cada día, obtenemos el día de la enumeración en base al día del indexado del `for` y si es fiesta continuamos el bucle, si se ha equivocado retornamos para que lo vuelva a introducir.

Si no es fiesta entramos en un bucle `while`, preguntaremos cuantas tareas tiene que realizar para darle el tamaño a la matriz, si el valor no es válido volvemos a empezar el bucle.

Para introducir las tareas tendremos que tener un bucle for que recorra la matriz creada y le asigne valores a cada posición (tareas).

Cuando termine de recorrer las tareas le preguntamos si está conforme con el día, si lo está pasaremos al siguiente día, hasta que estén todos completados.

Al final mostraremos un resumen de la semana.

el código es el siguiente:

```
using System;


namespace EjercicioPracticotema2
{
    public class Program
    {

        ToDoList[] semana = new ToDoList[7];
        public int z;
        int numTareas;
        public int i;

        public string[] ss;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            


            
            Console.WriteLine("planifica tu semana: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Lo primero sera decidir si es fiesta o no con 'true' 'False' ");


            for (p.i = 0; p.i < p.semana.Length; p.i++)
            {
                bool end = false;
                p.semana[p.i] = new ToDoList(); 

                Console.WriteLine("Dia " + (Dia)p.i + " es fiesta?");
                p.semana[p.i].DiaDeHoy = (Dia)p.i; 

                while (!end)
                {
                    

                    string s = Console.ReadLine();
                    bool diaLibre;
                    //Mejor parsear la información.
                    if (bool.TryParse(s, out diaLibre))
                    {
                        if (!diaLibre)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("escribe la cantidad de tareas");

                            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out p.numTareas))
                            {

                                p.semana[p.i].tareas = new string[p.numTareas];
                                Console.WriteLine("que tareas tienes?");
                                for (p.z = 0; p.z < p.numTareas; p.z++)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("escribe la tarea " + p.z);
                                    p.semana[p.i].tareas[p.z] = Console.ReadLine();
                                    // Console.WriteLine(p.i);
                                    //Console.WriteLine(p.z);

                                    bool end2 = false;

                                    while (!end2)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("escribe si estas conforme con las tareas con true o false");

                                        bool seguro;
                                        if (bool.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out seguro))
                                        {

                                            if (seguro)
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine("estas conforme");
                                                end2 = true;
                                                end = true;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine("no estas conforme.");

                                                Console.WriteLine("vuelve a escribir si " + (Dia)p.i-- + " es fiesta o no ");
                                                end2 = true;
                                                end = true;


                                            }


                                        }

                                        else
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine(" por favor escribe si estas conforme o no con true o false");

                                        }

                                    }
                                    

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("escribe la cantidad de tareas con numeros enteros");

                            }
                        }
                        else if (diaLibre)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Dia " + (Dia)p.i + " es fiesta");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("escribe si es fiesta o no es fiesta con TRUE o FALSE");
                    }


                }
                




            }
            foreach (Dia x in p.semana[p.i].tareas[p.z]) // aquí es donde me tira la excepción diciendome 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dia " + (Dia)p.i + "tienes las siguientes tareas: " + p.semana[p.i].tareas[p.z].ToString());

            }



        }

       
    }
    public enum Dia { Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sabado, Domingo }
    class ToDoList : ILibre
    {

        public Dia DiaDeHoy = Dia.Lunes;
        public string[] tareas;
        public bool diaLibre { get; set; }

        public void SetTareas(int x, string s) //Función para poner las tareas.
        {
            tareas[x] = s;
        }




    }
    interface ILibre
    {
        public bool diaLibre { get; set; }

    }
}
```

es decir en el bucle `foreach` me dice que me salgo del índice de la matriz pero no se muy bien por donde esta el fallo, e probado a mostrar los indexados para ver si los hace bien y yo creo que si, haber si me podrían decir por donde anda el fallo, aunque no hace falta que me digan la solución solo por donde anda el fallo para poder aprender y que no me vuelva a ocurrir ya que ahora no consigo ver donde falla ya que soy bastante novato. gracias un saludo

p.d. las variables locales las hice globales para que me de menos problemas y en la parte que preguntamos si esta seguro de sus tareas
end2 = true;
end = true;
igual no es lo mas correcto.

Comment: he probado el código y al final salen solo los días de fiesta y además salen que todos son fiesta esto porque es? alguien puede subir el codigo modificado porque a lo mejor no lo he entendido bien yo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios problemas logicamente derivados de la falta de experiencia, todos hemos estado ahi :)

Siendo estrictos, la excepción que te da esta motivada porque estas accediendo a `p.semana[p.i]`, y `p.i` en ese momento sale de un bucle que lo ha estado incrementando, con lo que su valor es 7, lo que esta fuera de los limites como bien te indica la excepción.

No voy a ir en detalle en todos los errores, pero si que una modificación que debes hacer es poner `diaLibre` a `true` si el usuario asi lo ha decidido:

```
else if (diaLibre)
{
     p.semana[p.i].diaLibre = true;
     Console.WriteLine("Dia " + (Dia)p.i + " es fiesta");
     break;
}
```

Esto será importante mas adelante al mostrar las tareas de la semana.

En cuanto al bucle que muestra los datos, yo te propongo modificarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach (ToDoList tareas in p.semana)
{
    if (tareas.diaLibre)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dia " + tareas.DiaDeHoy + " es fiesta");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dia " + tareas.DiaDeHoy + " tienes las siguientes tareas: ");
        if (tareas.tareas != null)
        {
            foreach (string t in tareas.tareas)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine(t);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Lo primero, modificamos el bucle para que sea un `foreach`, dado que tenemos que recorrer todo el array.

Una vez hecho esto, comprobamos si el dia en el que estamos es o no libre, para mostrar un mensaje diferente.

Si el dia no es libre, tenemos que recorrer las tareas que hay almacenadas, para ello usamos un bucle de la siguiente forma: `foreach (string t in tareas.tareas)`, para poder mostrar las mismas.

Comment: comprendo lo que me quieres decir  lo pondré en practica, mil gracias!!